# fmod() and fmodl() return wrong value in c

Tags: c, fmod

one example of my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    long double mod = fmod(0.06, 0.02);        
    printf("%Le", mod); //prints 2.000000e-02 instead of 0.000000e+00.
    long double mod1 = fmod(0.006, 0.002);        
    printf("%Le", mod1); //prints 0.000000e+00 correct.
    return 0;
}
```

how can i solve than problem, i tried to use `fmodf()` and `fmodl()` but i have the same problem on another values.

i have to work with long double so is there some way to solve that...

Comment: You use the same function twice.  Are you sure you’re testing what you think you’re testing?

Comment: Remember that [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) only uses double-precision arithmetic. Assigning the `double` result to a `long double` is kind of useless.

Comment: yes but i use fmodl but i still with the same problem

Comment: long double mod = fmodl((long double) 0.06, (long double) 0.02); .......                                                    
long double mod1 = fmodl((long double) 0.006, (long double) 0.002);..........                i wrote it like this and i have the same values.

Comment: Yup. One of the many pitfalls when working with floating point. Do study the duplicate carefully: it will be obvious once you've read that. A simple resolution in this case is to work in integer arithmetic and scale the result.

Comment: but the solve that they suggest didnt help my in my case. is there another solution.

Comment: you mean to do that .... (0.06 * 100) % (0.02*100) ??